# Python - Replace multiple characters in one file name

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am copying files from one folder into another. The files contain dashes '-' and spaces ' ' . For example, **test-file 123.dwg**
I need to replace those hyphens and spaces with underscores so it would look like this  **test_file_123.dwg**

I've tried this and it replaces the hyphen fine but no the space. If I comment out the one of them, the other works.

```
file = string.replace(NAME,"-", "_")  
file = string.replace(NAME," ", "_")
```

I have also tried this:

```
test = (' ', '-')  
file = string.replace(NAME, test, "_")
```

but no luck.
I am using Python 2.7.
All tips welcome.

Comment: No, both replacements work. The first replaces and stores the result in a string called `file`. The second also replaces and also stores the result in `file`. At that point it overwrites the previous contents of the variable. No surprise there; `x = 1` followed by `x = 2` yields in `x = 2`, not `x = 1 or 2 or any other previous value`.

Comment: You're storing it in a different variable, which you aren't using in the next statement.

Comment: @usr2564301 : This worked! It seems obvious now when you say it but I was going around in circles.

Answer (score 2):

This should help. Try chaining the `replace` method

```
string = "test-file 123.dwg"
file = string.replace("-", "_").replace(" ", "_")
print file
```

**Output:**

```
test_file_123.dwg
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
x = "test-102"
x = x.replace('-', '_')
print(x)
```

> test_102

The replace method should be called on your created string. Not the string class.